# Хорошая ли практика использовать переменные в трейтах? PHP

Tags: php, ооп, traits

У меня вопрос стоит ли использовать трейты вот таким образом:

```
trait getSmth{
    protected $smth = 10;
    public function getSmth(){
        return $this->smth;
    }
}
class Traitable_0{
    use getSmth;
    public function doAnything_0($anything){
        //тут делаем много всего в результате чего переменной
        //smth присваивается какое-то значение
        $this->smth = 'any value';
    }
}
class Traitable_1{
    use getSmth;
    public function doAnything_1($anything){
        //тут делаем много всего в результате чего переменной
        //smth присваивается какое-то значение
        $this->smth = 'any value';
    }
}
$traitable_0 = new Traitable_0();
$traitable_1 = new Traitable_1();
$traitable_0->doAnything_0('anything_0');
$traitable_1->doAnything_1('anything_1');
$rsltOfDoAnything_0 = $traitable_0->getSmth();
$rsltOfDoAnything_1 = $traitable_1->getSmth();
```

Вроде как получается очень удобно - видно как из класса получить значение переменной и не надо каждый раз писать функцию-getter и саму переменную в теле класса.
СОМНЕНИЕ: нету ли каких подводных камней в использовании трейтов таким образом, которые в дальнейшем усложнят расширяемость программы и читаемость кода.
P.S. у самого есть следующая мысль - тут нехороший момент, что при использовании трейта накладываются ограничения на название возвращаемой трейтом переменной - при желании использовать трейт во всех функциях придётся называть её как в трейте и если в трейте измениться название этой переменной или вдруг сам забудешь, что эта переменная "принадлежит" трейту и сам случайно её переназовёшь во время рефакторинга - не будет работать код и долго не будешь втыкать почему он не работает. Конечно, всё это дело нужно задокументировать как и вообще программу, однако, всё же лишний гемор. Стоит ли игра свеч?
Спасибо!

Comment: если вы в трейт реализуете какой-то функционал, то вполне логично, что там могут использоваться и переменные. Другой вопрос в том, что мне показалось, что вы хотите создать десятки трейтов с геттерами и сеттерами для разных переменных и на их основе классы строить. Это вот уже весьма сомнительная вещь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> нету ли каких подводных камней в использовании трейтов таким образом, которые в дальнейшем усложнят расширяемость программы и читаемость кода

Трейты обычно используются для включения узко-специального функционала в классы, там где не целесообразно наследование от какого-то другого класса. Если не будете усложнять сам трейт, то и расширяемость и читаемость только выиграют.

> тут нехороший момент, что при использовании трейта накладываются ограничения на название возвращаемой трейтом переменной

кроме геттера, сделайте еще и сеттер. Поскольку трейт обычно делается для узко-специального функционала, то сделайте "говорящие" геттер и сеттер, а самой переменной можете дать любое уникальное имя, исключающее коллизии. Например:

```
trait getSmth{
    protected $anyUniqueVariableNameForGetSmthTrait = 10;

    public function getSmth(){
        return $this->anyUniqueVariableNameForGetSmthTrait;
    }

    public function setSmth($smth) {
        $this->anyUniqueVariableNameForGetSmthTrait = $smth;
    }
}

class Traitable_0{
    use getSmth;
    public function doAnything_0($anything){
        //тут делаем много всего в результате чего переменной
        //smth присваивается какое-то значение
        $this->setSmth('any value');
    }
}
class Traitable_1{
    use getSmth;
    public function doAnything_1($anything){
        //тут делаем много всего в результате чего переменной
        //smth присваивается какое-то значение
        $this->setSmth('any value');
    }
}
```

> и сам случайно её переназовёшь во время рефакторинга

во время рефакторинга проблемы с трейтами в принципе те же, что и с рефакторингом базовых классов и их потомков при наследовании. Современные IDE поддерживают хорошие инструменты рефакторинга и поиска использования функций и переменных. Так что, проблема довольно надумана.